# Open physical drive from Linux

Tags: linux, filesystems

I'd like to open SD card as physical drive on Linux.
Somethink like:
CreateFile("PHYSICALDRIVE0",...)
On MS Windows.
How can I do it?

Comment: Don't you just read `/dev/sda1` or whatever?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All devices are represented as files under the `/dev` directory. These files can be opened exactly like regular files, e.g. `open(/dev/sdb, ...)`.

Disk-like devices are also symlinked in the directories `/dev/disk/by-id/`, `/dev/disk/by-path`, and `/dev/disk/by-uuid`, which makes it much easier to find to matching device file.

Answer (score 0):

Type df, to list all your filesystems mounted or unmounted. Once you know its address(everything in Linux is a file, so it will look like /dev/sda# or something like that) you can mount it with the mount command:

mount /path/to/drive /folder/to/mount/to

Comment: I guess Costa is asking not about mounting but about accessing partition contents as if it were a file.

Answer (score 0):

You open the block device special file (typically something like /dev/sdb) and then you can read/write blocks from it.

The interface is not clearly documented, it is a bug that there is no block(4) man page.

The sd(4) man page does help a bit though. The ioctls described there are probably valid for (some) other block devices as well.

Nowadays nearly all block devices appear as a "scsi drive" regardless of whether they are actually attached by scsi or not. This includes USB and (most) ATA drives.

Finding the right device to open may be a big part of the problem though, particularly if you have hotplug devices. You might be able to interrogate some things in /sys to find out what devices there are.